# Phaser not making any sound on Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, phaser-framework

I have this code for making sounds in my game built using Phaser which runs inside a browser on iOS and Android applications (wrappers).

While working fine on iOS, on Android I'm getting error messages and no sound at all when running the app in a webview.

My code:

```
preload:function() {
    game.load.audio('blast', 'assets/audio/blast.mp3');
    game.load.audio('collect_coin', 'assets/audio/Coin.mp3');
```

...

```
create:function() {         
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);
    blast=game.add.audio('blast');
    collect_coin=game.add.audio('collect_coin');
```

...

```
blast.play();
```

The error message from the console:

```
E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
```

When loading the files form a URL (http://...) there is a sound although its not working well... (and I want the files to load locally anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers don't support MP3, usually the best option to support most browsers is to have both an OGG & an MP3 version of the sound, and provide them both in a `game.add.audio('my', ['my.mp3', 'my.ogg'])` call.

As the [docs say](https://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Loader.html#audio), Phaser is clever enough to only actually load the first compatible file it finds, so don't worry about load time issues.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I tried different types of files and none of them worked. I think I'm missing something in the webview configuration / Android permissions... I also tried your suggestion with the same result.